# Has a quasi-polynomial $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ just rational coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, gm.general-mathematics

If $f(x) = a_k(n)n^k + \dots + a_1(n)n + a_0(n)$ is a [quasi-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial) (i.e. with $a_0, \dots, a_k$ being periodic functions) from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, does it follow that all the coefficient functions $a_i$ of $f$ just take rational values?

Comment: There's a somewhat immediate reduction to polynomials.

Comment: This question is certainly not of research level, but I felt like answering it (see below). It would have been more appropriate to ask it at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $s$ be a common period of the coefficient functions $a_i(n)$. Let $n$ be restricted to a residue class $n\equiv r\pmod{s}$. Then each $a_i(n)$ is constant $a_i(r)$, so $f(n)$ is a polynomial (depending on $r$). Taking any $k+1$ different numbers $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n\equiv r\pmod{s}$, and using that the corresponding values $f(n)$ are integers, simple linear algebra gives that the coefficients $a_i(r)$ are rational (cf. [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial)). This holds for every $r\in\mathbb{N}$, so we are done.